# How to hide email and password from cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, cypress, ui-automation

I hope you all are doing well. The problem is that I don't want to check email and passwords in version control. The idea is to use env and pass them in cypress tests and use secrets to provide value at runtime. But how can I setup that structure when I am running the tests locally? i.e. providing the value for those env variables. Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: I use `.env.local` files to hold local environment variables. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__env-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package (e.g. [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)) that will configure your environment variables from an external source that isn't version controlled: just make sure the source file (`.env`/`.env.local`/etc.) is listed in your `.gitignore`.